# boys and girls arrangement in a row

Tags: probability

> Three boys and two girls stand in a queue. The probability, that the number of boys ahead of
>
> every girl is at least one more then the number of girls ahead of her, is

**Attempt** Total number of ways of arranging $3$ boys and $2$ girls is $5!=120$

But i could not understand meaning of favourable cases, help me, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of boys ahead girls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811366/probability-of-boys-ahead-girls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Either a girl will start the sequence or be at the second position and will not acquire the last position as well. Hence, the required probability is: $$\boxed{\frac{\binom{3}{1}+\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{2}}=\frac12}$$

Also, this question has been [asked before on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811366/probability-of-boys-ahead-girls).

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If there are two girls in front (GGBBB) then the case is excluded.

If there are exactly one boy and one girl in front of a girl, then the case is excluded i.e. any case starting with (BGG) or (GBG).

Examples of favorable cases include:
(BBBGG), (BBGBG), (BBGGB).

> If you notice, as long as there is a string 'BB' somewhere and 'GG' does not start the queue then it is counted.