# Three boys and two girls stand in a queue. p, that the number of boys ahead of every girl is at least one more than number of girls ahead of her.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

I know a similar question has been asked earlier, but I can't make sense of it.

[Probability of boys ahead girls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811366/probability-of-boys-ahead-girls)

[boys and girls arrangement in a row](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567449/boys-and-girls-arrangement-in-a-row)

question:

> Three boys and two girls stand in a queue. The probability, that the number of boys ahead of every girl is at least one more than the number of girls ahead of her, is?

My attempt, as it's easier to calculate the complement, let's do that

case 1:- No boys ahead of girls. There are $2!3!=12$

case 2- At most one boy ahead of the two girls.  There are $^3C_1$ways of selecting the boy in the front,and $2!2!$ ways of permuting the remaining two girls and boys, so there are $^3C_1 \cdot 2!2!$ ways here, which is $12$.

Which means that the probability of the complement is $\frac{4}{5}$.  However, the actual answer is $\frac{3}{4}$. Why is my answer wrong?

source:- JEE Advance 2014

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, $\frac34$ **has** to be a wrong answer, because there are are a total of $\binom52 = 10$ possible arrangements, and a Pr of $\frac34$ would imply that there are $7.5$ favorable cases, which is obviously absurd.

As for the correct answer, a girl can't head the queue (*because there would be $0$ girls ahead of her so by the rule, there would need to be $1$ boy ahead of her*), it is easy to compute the favorable configurations.

See the one below starting with rear as the leftmost with $3$ boxes where the $2$ boys can be fitted in

$\boxed{Box}\; G\;\boxed{Box}\;\boxed{GB}\;\boxed{Box}$

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we can fit the remaining two boys in $\binom{2+3-1}{3-1}= 6$ ways,  but we can't put both the boys in the first  box, as it would break the constraint for the first girl,

Thus favorable ways = $5$ against total combos of $\binom53 = 10$

so the correct answer is $\frac5{10} = \frac12$

Comment: You misssed one, GBGBB.

Comment: @3rdMoment: Yes, thanks I realized, was trying to figure out a formula rather than listing

Comment: Are you counting complementary cases?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: No, I counted the valid cases.

Comment: The reason for my confusion is that if an arrangement ends with a girl, there must be one girl and three boys ahead of her.  Did you mean that an arrangement cannot start with a girl since there would be no boys ahead of her?  3rdMoment pointed out the other invalid case.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I have taken the rear to be leftmost. (Rear) GBGBB (Front) is covered.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I have added a few words "...end *at head of queue*.." for greater clarity

Comment: I think your comment that you have taken the rear to be the leftmost is clearer than what you wrote in your answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I have edited to avoid all confusion. The  main idea was to solve it in a different way using stars and bars

Comment: oh, I missed this it appeared once and then disppaered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are ${5 \choose 2 }= 10$ ways of ordering 3 boys and 2 girls.

We know a boy has to be first, so there are ${4 \choose 2 }= 6$ ways of ordering the remaining 2 boys and 2 girls.

But we have to remove the case where the girls are second and third. This leaves 5 possible orderings:
bgbgb, bgbbg, bbggb, bbgbg, bbbgg.

So the probability should be $5/10 = 1/2$.

Comment: oh, thanks! But why doesn't my method work? What have I missed?

Comment: More generally, if there are $B$ boys and $G$ girls, where $B\ge G$, the probability is $(B+1-G)/(B+1)$, see [Bertrand's ballot theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed)

Comment: I think you missed the cases where there is one girl in front but the second girl could be third, fourth, or fifth. This is 6*3! =36 extra permutations, which added to the 24 you already listed gives 60, and 60/5!= 1/2.

Comment: why  are there $\5chose2$ ways?

Comment: shouldn't it be $5!$?

Comment: I am using combinations, with the girls and boys indistinguishable. If you use permutations where the identities of the individual boys and girls matter then you get 5! possibilities. It is much easier to enumerate the possibilities if you do the former.

Answer (score 1):

What matters here are the relative positions of the boys and girls.  Therefore, we can take as our sample space the $\binom{5}{2}$ ways we can choose two of the five positions for the girls.

There are two constraints:

1. A girl cannot be in the first position since there would be an equal number of boys and girls ahead of her, namely none.
2. The two girls cannot be in the second and third positions since there would be an equal number of boys and girls ahead of the girl in the third position, namely one of each.

Hence, there can be no girls in the first position and at most one girl in the second or third positions.

If there is exactly one girl in the second or third positions, there must be one girl in the fourth or fifth positions.  We must choose whether a girl occupies the second position or third position and whether a girl occupies the fourth position or fifth position, giving $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ possible arrangements.

If no girls are in the second or third positions, the girls must occupy the fourth and fifth positions, giving one additional favorable case.

Hence, the probability that the number of boys ahead of each girl is at least one more than the number of girls ahead of her is
$$\frac{2 \cdot 2 + 1}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2}$$

*What is wrong with your approach?*

Since you took order into account, there are $5!$ arrangements in our sample space.

You wanted to count the number of elements that are not favorable.  The complementary event is that there are at most as many boys ahead of a girl as there are girls ahead of a girl.

*No boys ahead of girls*:  This means there must be a girl in the first position.  There are two ways to choose that girl.  That leaves four ways to pick the position of the other girl.  The boys can then be arranged in the remaining three spaces in $3!$ ways, so there are $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3! = 48$ such cases.

The other case which is not favorable has a boy in the first position followed by girls in the second and third positions.  Your description does not make this clear.

*A boy in the first position followed by girls in the second and third positions*:  There are three ways to select the boy who will occupy the first position, $2!$ ways to arrange the girls in the second and third positions, and $2!$ ways to arrange the remaining two boys in the fourth and fifth positions, giving $3 \cdot 2!2! = 12$ such arrangements.

Hence, there are
$$2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3! + 3 \cdot 2!2!$$
unfavorable cases.  Hence, the probability that the number of boys ahead of each girl is at least one more than the number of girls ahead of her is
$$1 - \frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3! + 3 \cdot 2!2!}{5!} = 1 - \frac{60}{120} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: You said 4 ways to pick the position of the other girl, however, the opposite would be at most one  boy can be ahead o a girl, would it not?

Comment: If there is a girl in the first position, there are four ways to place the other girl since there are four other positions.  Your second comment needs clarification.  I explained what the other unfavorable case is.

Comment: I feel that the complement of the given event is that there is at most one boy ahead of the girl, than the number of girls ahead of her

Comment: What you wrote is not very clear.  The complementary event is that there are at most as many boys as girls ahead of each girl.  If there is a girl in the first position, there are zero boys and zero girls ahead of the first girl.  If the girls are in the first and third positions, there is one boy and one girl ahead of the second girl.  Those are the two ways that there can be at most as many boys as girls ahead of each girl.

Comment: oh,ok. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Let us see the cases. (In the $k$th case we will give a girl the $k$th position, and see the possibilities of the other girl at position $P>k$ - since the $P<k$ would have been already counted.)

**Case 1**:
A girl is at 1st pos.
But, this is not possible as there would be no boy ahead of her.
**0 cases**.

**Case 2**:
A girl is in second pos(2 ways).
Note that a boy should be ahead of her (3 ways).
The second girl can't be at the 3rd place (why?).
So, the third place has to be a boy (2 ways from the remaining boys).
Note that the remaining girl and boy can be ordered in any way in the remaining places. (2! = 2 ways).
Total cases = 2 x 3 x 2 x 2 = **24 cases**.

**Case 3**:
A girl is in 3rd pos. (2 ways)
There are 2 boys ahead of her (why?). (3P2 = 6 ways)
The remaining boy and girl, again, can be arranged in any way. (2! = 2 ways)
Total cases = 2 x 6 x 2 = **24 cases**.

**Case 4**:
A girl is at the 4th place. (2 ways)
Note that we will not count a girl ahead of her as we have already counted that in Case 2.
So, the remaining girl only has one place( behind the first one).
The 3 boys can be ordered in the first 3 places in any way. (3! = 6 ways)
Total cases = 2 x 6 = **12 cases**.

**Case 5** is *not possible* as we have 2 girls (and placing one girl in 5th pos. wouldn't work as we need to place the other girl behind her (why?)).

Favourable Outcomes = 24+24+12 = **60**.
Total outcomes = 5! = **120**.
Thus, **P = 1/2**. (This has been answered before me too, although this is a slightly easier approach.)

Comment: A suggestion about the wording:  your $k$th case is the *first* girl is in the $k$th place.